# Listings: different counters for different listing environments

Tags: listings, environments, numbering, counters

How do I create two lstlisting environments that each have its own counter?

If I use for example

```
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {}

\lstnewenvironment{program}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {}
```

And then

```
\begin{algorithm}{Algorithm caption}{alg-label}
...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{program}{Program caption}{prg-label}
...
\end{program}
```

Then they will share the counter, i.e. it will result for example in

```
Algorithm 1.1
    ...
Program 1.2
    ...
```

I would like the counting to be independent for different listing environments.

I also use the caption package to create a nice caption. I've already tried many things but none really successfuly. The only way that I found that indicates how to change the counter/file extension is via i.e. \DeclareCaptionType[fileext=alg]{algorithm} but the problem is that this command already defines a new environment so I don't know how to use it together with a new listings environment and the caption package. I'm using for example the following settings:

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution in the spirit of [Elenaher](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1435/elenaher)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments/3998#3998):

```
\newcounter{algorithm}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{algorithm}}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}}

\newcounter{program}
\lstnewenvironment{program}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{program}}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {\addtocounter{program}{1}}
```

Then the following:

```
\begin{algorithm}{Algorithm caption}{alg-label}
...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}{Another algorithm caption}{another-alg-label}
...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{program}{Program caption}{prg-label}
...
\end{program}
```

results in:

```
Algorithm 1.1
    ...
Algorithm 1.2
    ...
Program 1.1
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should try to invoke manually the command `setcounter` to change the counter of `lstlisting` like that :

```
\setcounter{lstlisting}{value}
```

Thus, you will be able to re-initialize the counter for each new environments.

Then you could do more complicated things like automating the invocation of setcounter with the values of the label.

Comment: You are right,thanks! I looked at this and related commands before but I didn't see a clean way to use them. Well, I guess that letting all new environments share the same counter and changing it is not very clean, more of a hack, but then again, I don't know that much about LaTeX. I'll post the solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in [fraktalek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4068/100076) was explicitly shown. I could not use the code provided and replicate his output. Specifically, the captions and (I assume) labels are missing.

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209560/100076) which helped me out, noting that there is a caption field in `lstset`. So here's a full working example with both captions and labels in two custom `lstnewenvironment`s.

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{couriers}  % Typewriter font which supports bold
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{algorithm}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{algorithm}}
    \lstset
    {
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        frame = tb,
        caption={[#1]{#1}},      % <------------- NOTICE
        label={#2},              % <------------- NOTICE
    }
}{\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}}

\newcounter{program}
\lstnewenvironment{program}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{program}}
    \lstset
    {
        language=Python,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        frame = tb,
        caption={[#1]{#1}},
        label={#2},
    }
}{\addtocounter{program}{1}}


\begin{document}

Text before, referencing Algorithm \ref{alg-label}.

\begin{algorithm}{Something descriptive}{alg-label}
#include <stddef.h>
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}{Something descriptive}{alg-label2}
char * foo(unsigned char bar);
\end{algorithm}

\begin{program}{Something descriptive}{prog-label}
def foo(bar: int) -> str:
    print(bar)
\end{program}

Text after, referencing Algorithm \ref{alg-label2} and Program \ref{prog-label}.

\end{document}
```

Which generates...

[image: LaTeX Listings different counters with captions and labels]