# How to get autoref working with different counters for different listing environments?

Tags: hyperref, listings, cross-referencing, counters

In my document I want several different custom listing environments. The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments/4068#4068) from [fraktalek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1433/fraktalek) works like a charm, except for one thing: `\autoref` doesn't work for me. I have tried the following:

```
\newcounter{algorithm}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]{
        \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
        \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{algorithm}}
        \lstset{#1}
} {\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}}

\newcounter{program}
\lstnewenvironment{program}[1][]{
        \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
        \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{program}}
        \lstset{#1}
} {\addtocounter{program}{1}}

\def\algorithmautorefname{Algorithm}
\def\programautorefname{Program}
```

But, in my document,

```
\autoref{alg:firstalgorithm}, \autoref{prg:firstprogram}, \autoref{alg:secondalgorithm}
```

returns

> Listing 1.1, Listing 1.1, Listing 1.2.

The separate numbering is correct, but autoref does not recognize the separate counters. However, if I use

```
\def\lstlistingautorefname{Code fragment}
```

instead, the result changes to

> Code fragment 1.1, Code fragment 1.1, Code fragment 1.2.

I have tried putting this command inside the `\lstnewenvirontment` commands, but this again gave

> Listing 1.1, Listing 1.1, Listing 1.2

as a result. Obviously, I would like to result to be

> Algorithm 1.1, Program 1.1, Algorithm 1.2.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/how-to-get-autoref-working-with-different-counters-for-different-listing-environm/25018#25018), I arrived at the problem that I could no longer let the new environments float.

After some further research, I now can present a new way to tackle the original problem. Instead of creating a new float using `\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}`, you can also create a floating container and put a non-floating lstlisting-environment in it. [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) suggested to use the [float](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/) package. Since I have adopted [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow) for other floats in my documents, I have use that package here too. The [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow) package extends the layout possibilities for floats and works well together with [caption](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption).

We begin with loading the necessary packages

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelsep=period,
    labelfont=bf, justification=centerlast]{caption}    
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{listings}
```

Next, we create the desired floating containers with [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow)

```
\DeclareNewFloatType{algorithm}{name=Algorithm, placement=htbp, within=section}
\DeclareNewFloatType{codefragment}{name=Code fragment, placement=htbp,within=section}
```

The name will be used for captions and references, within specifies that the new floats will be numbered within sections.

We want captions to be placed above our newly created floats. Since [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow) handles the caption position and puts them below floats by default (whatever the place of `\caption` inside the float), we have to specify this by

```
\floatsetup[algorithm]{style=plaintop}
\floatsetup[codefragment]{style=plaintop}
```

and probably also

```
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
```

Now, in our document, we can create an algoritm or code fragment with

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Hello world!}
\label{alg:myfirstalgorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello world!
How are you today?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{codefragment}
\caption{Hello world!}
\label{alg:myfirstalgorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello world!
How are you today?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{codefragment}
```

This solutions allows the listings to float with the desired caption. It is also easy to create a list the new float types:

```
\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}
\listof{codefragment}{List of Code fragments}
```

By creating an appropriate floatbox with the floatrow package, it would also be possible to compare code fragments side by side easily. Here follows a more elaborate example, with separate formatting for pseudo code and C++/matlab code.

```
\documentclass{article}

% math  
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % ams math
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % ams symbols

% fonts & typesetting
\usepackage{mathpazo}               % Palatino & Pazo math
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{berasans}  % bera sans and mono scaled to fit with Palatino
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{microtype}                  % better typesetting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % font encoding
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}            % input encoding
\usepackage{textcomp}                   % required for the upquote option of the listings package

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelsep=period,
    labelfont=bf, justification=centerlast]{caption}    % nice captions
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{listings}

% create new numbered floats for different types of listings
\DeclareNewFloatType{algorithm}{name=Algorithm, placement=htbp, within=section}
\DeclareNewFloatType{codefragment}{name=Code fragment, placement=htbp,within=section}

% captions above code floats
\floatsetup[algorithm]{style=plaintop}
\floatsetup[codefragment]{style=plaintop}


% pseudo language definition
\lstdefinelanguage{pseudo}{
morekeywords={for, for all, while, do, end, if, then, else, return, divides, min, max, require, ensure, print},
sensitive=false,
mathescape=true,
escapechar=`}

% pseudo style definition
\lstdefinestyle{pseudo}{
language=pseudo,
basicstyle=\rmfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
columns=[l]fullflexible,    
showstringspaces=false,
numbers=left,       
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
tabsize=2,
aboveskip={0pt},
belowskip={0pt},
frame=lines}

% normal code style definition
\lstdefinestyle{realcode}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\textit,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    aboveskip={0pt},
    belowskip={0pt},
    upquote=true,
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=lines,
    columns=[c]fixed}

% Matlab and C++style definition
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{language=matlab,style=realcode}     
\lstdefinestyle{C++}{language=C++,style=realcode}       


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}
\listof{codefragment}{List of Code fragments}

\section{Computing $N!$}

Check out the pseudo code in \autoref{alg:myfirstalgorithm}, and then the Matlab and C++ equivalents in  \autoref{alg:myfirstprogram} and \autoref{alg:mysecondprogram}.

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Compute $N!$.}
\label{alg:myfirstalgorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=pseudo]
$z \gets 1$ 
for $k\in[1,\dotsc,N]$ do
    $z \gets z\cdot k$
return $z$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{codefragment}
\caption{Compute $N!$, Matlab implementation.}
\label{alg:myfirstprogram}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
function z = computefactorial(N)
    z = 1;
    for k = 1 : N
        z = z * k;
    end
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{codefragment}

\begin{codefragment}
\caption{Compute $N!$, C++ implementation.}
\label{alg:mysecondprogram}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=C++]
int z = computefactorial(int N)  { 
    z = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++) { 
        z = z * k;
    }
    return z;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{codefragment}



\end{document}
```

The output of this is

[image: output of code]

A weakness of this method is that in the document, you have to nest two environments. This gives more clutter than [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/how-to-get-autoref-working-with-different-counters-for-different-listing-environm/25018#25018).

Ideally, the `\lstnewenvironment` action should be modified to create a seperate counter for newly generated environments.

Suggestions and remarks are still very welcome! This is the first time I'm diving this deep in the details, but I'm enjoying it!

Comment: This looks great. It is not uncommon (=common?) to have nested environments. For example, using the `tabular` environment inside the (floating) `table` environment is the *de facto* way of presenting standard tables in LaTeX.

Comment: In my opinion, line numbers are not so useful. Their existence makes the code look stuffy.

Answer (score 5):

The solution I'm proposing here is adequate for relatively small documents, but will not work for more complex documents where the user wants to produce something like a `\listofalgorithms` or `\listofprograms`. Since this was not specified in the original question, it is not included here. However, I'm sure it is easy to extend it to include such requirements using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), for example.

> Some background to the solution...
>
> One problem is that the `lstlisting` environment provided by the
> [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is special. It's
> contents has to be parsed in a way such that nothing is expanded,
> except for `\end{lstlisting}`. That's why it cannot be broken up
> using:
>
> ```
> \newenvironment{myenvironment}[1][]{%
>   \begin{lstlisting}[#1]% Begin listing
> }{\end{lstlisting}}% End listing
> ```
>
> giving you a error during compilation. As a consolation, the
> `listings` package provides an alternative in the form of
>
> ```
> \lstnewenvironment{<name>}[<number>][<opt. default arg.>]{<start code>}{<end code>}
> ```
>
> analogous to LaTeX's
> [`\newenvironment{nam}[args][opt]{begdef}{enddef}`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-19.html)
> definition. However, merely using this definition as-is in the
> [solution to different counters for different listing
> environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments/4068#4068)
> causes [`hyperref` to complain in the following
> way](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyperdupdest)
>
> ```
> ! pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
> (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
> ```
>
> This is because the same counter is used - namely `lstlisting` -
> across the newly defined listing environments. In fact, they are the
> same environments, just with different names (due to the command
> `\renewcommand\lstlistingname{<name>}`). This warning motives why
> using
>
> ```
> \def\algorithmautorefname{Algorithm}
> \def\programautorefname{Program}
> ```
>
> does not sway `\autoref{...}` from using the correct reference title,
> since `\autoref{...}` still sees each newly defined environment
> (`algorithm` and `program`) as `lstlisting`.

One proposed solution would be to add some macros that both prints a correct caption (albeit manually) and correctly hyperlinks to the respective `lstlisting`. This is done by introducing a "pre-hook" to each new `\lstnewenvironment` and modifying the way in which parameters are passed to it. Caption and label support via `listings`' `caption={...}` and `label=...` is dropped in lieu of a manual alternative. This way `lstlisting` environments are always using a incrementally different counter in the background, thereby avoiding the `hyperref` duplicate destination warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\listingcaption}[2]{%
  \parbox{0.95\textwidth}{% Width of caption is 95% of \textwidth
    \leftskip=0pt plus.5fil% These 3 lines allow for a
    \rightskip=0pt plus-.5fil% justification=centerlast option similar
    \parfillskip=0pt plus1fil% to that offered by the `caption` package
    \small \textbf{#1~\thealgorithm}.\ #2% Caption formatting
  }%
}
% ================== ALGORITHM ==================
\newcounter{algorithm}
%\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thesection.\arabic{algorithm}}% Algorithm counter definition
\newcommand{\algorithmprehook}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{algorithm}% Increment counter for correct reference
  \listingcaption{Algorithm}{#1}% Algorithm caption
  \label{#2}% Label algorithm
}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[3][]{% \begin{algorithm}[<listings options>]{<caption>}{<label>}...
  \algorithmprehook{#2}{#3}% Algorithm pre-hook
  \lstset{#1}% Set listings options
} {}% ...\end{algorithm}
\def\algorithmautorefname{Algorithm}% Autoref caption

% ================== PROGRAM ==================
\newcounter{program}
%\renewcommand{\theprogram}{\thesection.\arabic{program}}% Program counter definition
\newcommand{\programprehook}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{program}% Increment counter for correct reference
  \listingcaption{Program}{#1}% Program caption
  \label{#2}% Label program
}
\lstnewenvironment{program}[3][]{% \begin{program}[<listings options>]{<caption>}{<label>}...
  \programprehook{#2}{#3}% Program pre-hook
  \lstset{#1}% Set listings options
} {}% ...\end{program}    
\def\programautorefname{Program}% Autoref caption

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{algorithm}[]{My first algorithm. This is an extremely long caption, giving a detailed %
description of the context and code. Justification is ``centerlast''}{alg:firstalgorithm}
  Here is some algorithm code;
  Then some more code;
  And it ends here.
\end{algorithm}

\begin{program}[]{My first program}{prg:firstprogram}
  Here is some program code;
  Which is a little shorter.
\end{program}

\begin{algorithm}[]{My second algorithm}{alg:secondalgorithm}
  The final algorithm code is very short.
\end{algorithm}

\autoref{alg:firstalgorithm}, \autoref{prg:firstprogram}, \autoref{alg:secondalgorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Alternative lstlisting environments (algorithm+program) with correct caption, counter and hyperlinks]

The macro `\listingcaption{<caption label>}{<caption>}`, which provides the manual caption support, takes 2 mandatory arguments. `<caption label>` is the type of label (Algorithm or Program in this case) and `<caption>` is the actual caption. The formatting of the caption is similar to the specification

```
\captionsetup[<float type>]{%
  font=small,%
  format=plain,%
  labelsep=period,%
  labelfont=bf,%
  justification=centerlast%
}
```

supported by the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). The option `justification=centerlast` was obtained from [this recent blog entry](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/01/center-last-line-in-paragraph.html), originally suggested by Victor Eijkhout's [*TeX by Topic*](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html).

When using the `float` package for managing captions, counters and `\listof...` entries, it is advisable to also forego using the `listings` options for `caption={...}` and `label=...`.

Comment: This works, and I now understand the problem a bit better. The lack of support for lists of algorithms is not a problem indeed, although I'm working on a rather large document (a currently ca. 160 page algorithms & programming exercise book).

Comment: With this solution, two new questions arise: 1) is there a difference between `\renewcommand{\theprogram}{\thesection.\arabic{program}}%` and `\numberwithin{program}{section}` (both seem to give the desired result) and 2) is it possible to use the formatting defined by the caption package (in this case `\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelsep=period,
 labelfont=bf, justification=centerlast]{caption}`?

Comment: @MartinKS: 1) Yes. `\renewcommand{\theprogram}{\thesection.\arabic{program}}` only redefines the way the counter `program` is typeset, while `\numberwithin{program}{section}` also executes `\@addtoreset{program}{section}`, meaning `program` will be reset (effectively `\setcounter{program}{0}`) whenever you use `\section[..]{...}`. 2) I've updated my answer to reflect the settings you requested from the `caption` package. This was done by adding a macro `\listingcaption{<caption label>}{<caption>}` that now contains the relevant formatting.

Comment: I have discovered a major flow in your solution. I have also found a way to avoid this problem and solve the problem in a different way. I will post that solution separately. The problem is that when you drop the listings caption option, the caption becomes separated from the code if the float option from the listings package is used for the environment. It seems that the caption is no longer connected to the floating algorithm/program environment.

Comment: This is true, since the caption is inherently separate (it is inserted manually) from the newly defined listings environment. You never suggested that your listing should be able to float using `listings`' `float` option. That's why I suggested using the `float` package. This *should* allow the two to float together.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that, but it is quite vital for me. I'm interested in your view on the solution I just proposed.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with the same problem for a couple of days. In my case, I couldn't wrap the listings in floats, since I wanted them to be able to break across multiple pages. And it isn't really desirable for me to break up the caption and label in separate arguments, as in [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/how-to-get-autoref-working-with-different-counters-for-different-listing-environm/25018#25018), since I want to be able to use the listing environment's built-in caption support to make it easy to re-style each listing environment using `\captionsetup`.

I'm no TeXpert, but I've managed to hack together the following solution that seems to work. It's based on similar ideas as discussed [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/multiple-listings-styles) here on TeX.SX. The implementation is quite rough in the edges, but it's based on the idea of patching `\lst@MakeCaption` to replace all hard-coded references to the `\c@lstlisting` counter with per-environment counters. Also, it integrates the fix already presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/multiple-listings-styles) to give each listing environment a separate "List of ...".

What I ended up with is a macro `\newcustomlstenvironment` that wraps `\lstnewenvironment`, but takes as additional arguments the caption/autoref name to be associated with the new listing environment, and the auxiliary file extension to be used for producing the list of listings.

One problem that I've tried to accommodate (although not very elegantly), is that both the `hyperref` package and the `caption` package will wrap the `\lst@MakeCaption` macro. And depending on the order these two packages have been loaded, one might wrap the macro before the other. Hence, it's a bit of work to identify the actual renamed macro that should be patched in place of `\lst@MakeCaption`.

Finally, since the listings package provides no means for using `\lstinputlisting` with different listing environments, I've also wrapped this macro in a `\lstinput<name of environment>` macro that is environment-specific.

So here is an MWE (although it's not that "minimal"):

```
\documentclass{book}

% Packages needed by our "hack"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[hang,bf,small,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THE HACK %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
  \global\@namedef{cmdname@lst@MakeCaption}{lst@MakeCaption}

  \@ifpackageloaded{caption}{
    % If hyperref is loaded before caption, then hyperref will have wrapped \lst@MakeCaption first in \NROrg@lst@MakeCaption
    \xpatchcmd\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption{\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption}{\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption}
      {%
        \global\@namedef{cmdname@lst@MakeCaption}{NROrg@lst@MakeCaption}
        \global\@namedef{cmdname@caption@lst@MakeCaption}{lst@MakeCaption}% caption package's override of \lst@MakeCaption
      }{%
        \global\@namedef{cmdname@lst@MakeCaption}{caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}
        \global\@namedef{cmdname@caption@lst@MakeCaption}{NROrg@lst@MakeCaption}% caption package's override of \lst@MakeCaption
      }
  }{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
    % If caption is loaded before hyperref, then caption will have wrapped \lst@MakeCaption first in \caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption
    \xpatchcmd\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}
      {\global\@namedef{cmdname@lst@MakeCaption}{caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}}{\global\@namedef{cmdname@lst@MakeCaption}{NROrg@lst@MakeCaption}}
  }{}

  % Define convenient macro for patching the actual (potentially wrapped) \lst@MakeCaption
  \gdef\@patch@lst@MakeCaption#1#2{
    \expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname\cmdname@lst@MakeCaption\endcsname{#1}{#2}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \@backslashchar lst@MakeCaption}\@ehd}
  }

  % Define convenient macro for patching the caption package's re-implementation of \lst@MakeCaption
  \gdef\@patch@caption@lst@MakeCaption#1#2{
    \@ifundefined{cmdname@caption@lst@MakeCaption}{}{
      \expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname\cmdname@caption@lst@MakeCaption\endcsname{#1}{#2}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch caption's \@backslashchar lst@MakeCaption}\@ehd}
    }
  }

  % Patch ToC-stuff in \lst@MakeCaption
  \global\@namedef{ext@lstlisting}{lol}
  \global\@patch@lst@MakeCaption
    {\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}}
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@lstlisting}}{lstlisting}}
  \global\@patch@lst@MakeCaption
    {\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}}
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@lstlisting}}{lstlisting}}
}

\gdef\@customlstenvironmenthook#1{
  % Override listing name as shown in caption
  \def\lstlistingname{\@nameuse{#1name}}
  % Override counter as shown in caption
  \expandafter\let\csname c@lstlisting\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname thelstlisting\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname theHlstlisting\expandafter\endcsname\csname theH#1\endcsname
  %
  % Prepend #1- to \theHlstnumber to make this hyperref counter unique too
  % (otherwise, hyperref will complain with "destination with the same identifier
  % (name{lstnumber.X.Y.Z}) has been already used, duplicate ignored").
  % Thanks to Heiko "the man" Oberdiek!!
  % (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/vO5PaIkhfkE/ouW-6192yd4J)
  \begingroup
    \global\let\gtmp@theHlstnumber\theHlstnumber
    \toks@\expandafter{\theHlstnumber}%
    \xdef\gtmp@theHlstnumber{#1-\the\toks@}%
  \endgroup
  \let\theHlstnumber\gtmp@theHlstnumber
  %
  % Patch \lst@MakeCaption to use the counter of our customized lstlisting environment.
  \@patch@lst@MakeCaption
    {\ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\expandafter\lst@HRefStepCounter\else
      \expandafter\refstepcounter\fi {lstlisting}}
    {\ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\expandafter\lst@HRefStepCounter\else
      \expandafter\refstepcounter\fi {#1}}
  %
  % Patch ToC output from \lst@MakeCaption so we get a separate "List of ..." for each environment.
  \@patch@lst@MakeCaption
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@lstlisting}}{lstlisting}\lst@name}
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}{#1}\lst@name}
  \@patch@lst@MakeCaption
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@lstlisting}}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}}
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}{#1}{\protect\numberline\expandafter{\csname the#1\endcsname}\lst@@caption}}
  %
  % Now, patch caption's implementation of \lst@MakeCaption, so we may style each environment differently using \captionsetup
  \@patch@caption@lst@MakeCaption
    {\caption@setoptions{lstlisting}}
    {\caption@setoptions{#1}}
  \@patch@caption@lst@MakeCaption
    {\caption@begin{lstlisting}}
    {\caption@begin{#1}}
}

% Usage: \newcustomlstenvironment
%          {<Environment name>}{<Aux extension>}{<Caption/autref name>}
%          [<number>][<opt. default arg.>]{<starting code>}{ending code>} <-- These are passed directly to \lstnewenvironment
\lst@UserCommand\newcustomlstenvironment#1#2#3#4#{%
  \newcustomlstenvironment@{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}
\gdef\newcustomlstenvironment@#1#2#3#4#5#6{
  % Define separate counter for our customized lstlisting environment.
  % Note: only supports numbering with or without chapter number first (same as lstlisting).
  \lst@ifnumberbychapter
    \newcounter{#1}[chapter]
    \global\@namedef{the#1}%
      {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \arabic{#1}}
  \else
    \newcounter{#1}
    \global\@namedef{the#1}{\arabic{#1}}
  \fi
  %
  % Hyperref has separate counter that needs a unique name.
  % Again, thanks to Mr. Oberdiek!
  \global\@namedef{theH#1}%
    {lst.#1-\csname the\@ifundefined{theHchapter}{}{H}chapter\endcsname .\arabic{#1}}
  %
  % Override autoref names for our environment.
  \global\@namedef{#1name}{#3}
  \global\@namedef{#1autorefname}{#3}
  %
  % Define aux extension
  \global\@namedef{ext@#1}{#2}
  %
  % Create new listing environment as usual, by calling \lstnewenvironment
  % Note: #4 contains something like "[N][]", corresponding to [<number>][<opt. default arg.>]
  %       arguments of \lstnewenvironment (see listings doc, §4.16).
  \lstnewenvironment{#1}#4{
    \@customlstenvironmenthook{#1}
    %
    % Contents passed to {<starting code} of \lstnewenvrionment (e.g. \lstset{#1,..})
    #5%
  }{%
    % Contents passed to {<ending code>} of \lstnewenvrionment
    #6%
  }
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname lstinput#1\endcsname[2][]{
    \begingroup
      \@customlstenvironmenthook{#1}
      #5%
      \lstinputlisting[##1]{##2}
      #6%
    \endgroup
  }
}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EXAMPLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Packages used by our example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{samplecode.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{captionpos=b,numbers=left,backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,1}}

\makeatletter
\newcustomlstenvironment{codesnippet}{locodesnippet}{Code Snippet}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1,language=C,frame=tb,captionpos=t,backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{1,1,0.9}}%
   \csname lst@SetFirstNumber\endcsname}
  {\csname lst@SaveFirstNumber\endcsname}

\newcustomlstenvironment{algorithm}{loalgorithm}{Algorithm}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1,language=C,frame=tblr,captionpos=t,backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,1,0.9}}%
   \csname lst@SetFirstNumber\endcsname}
  {\csname lst@SaveFirstNumber\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listof{lstlisting}{List of Listings}
\listof{codesnippet}{List of Code Snippets}
\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test 1},label={listing:test1},name={test}]
Line 1
Line 2
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test 2},label={listing:test2},name={test}]
Line 3
Line 4
\end{lstlisting}

Referencing normal listings: \autoref{listing:test1}, \autoref{listing:test2}.

\begin{codesnippet}[caption={First snippet},label={snippet:first},name={hello}]
#include <stdio.h>
\end{codesnippet}

\begin{algorithm}[caption={First algorithm},label={alg:first},name={myalg}]
A
B
\end{algorithm}

\begin{codesnippet}[caption={Second snippet},label={snippet:second},name={hello}]
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{codesnippet}

Referencing snippets: \autoref{snippet:first}, \autoref{snippet:second}.

\begin{algorithm}[caption={Second algorithm},label={alg:second},name={myalg}]
C
\end{algorithm}

Referencing algorithms: \autoref{alg:first}, \autoref{alg:second}.

\chapter{Input}

\lstinputcodesnippet[caption={this is my caption},label={snippet:input}]{samplecode.c}

Referencing snippet: \autoref{snippet:input}.

\end{document}
```

I've used the book class to demonstrate that chapter numbers are properly added as prefix to the reference numbers. The result will look something like this:

[image: List of Listings]
[image: List of Code Snippets]
[image: List of Algorithms]
[image: Chapter]
[image: Input]

As this is my first time posting here, I would be very happy to get some feedback or suggestions! Also, I'm sorry to re-open a several-year-old post, but I thought this might be helpful.

### Edit

It turned out that to be able to style the caption of each listing environment differently using `\captionsetup`, it was also necessary to patch the changes that have been made to `\lst@MakeCaption` by the `caption` package. And depending on whether `hyperref` was loaded before `caption` or not, the command that needs to be patched in this case could either be the `\lst@MakeCaption` or the `\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption` command.

I have updated the code above with the changes needed to get `\captionsetup` to work. As an example, the following can be added to the end of the preamble

```
\captionsetup[codesnippet]{box=colorbox,boxcolor={yellow}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{box=colorbox,boxcolor={cyan},skip=-1pt}
```

to make the listing captions look like this:
[image: Styled captions]