# How to place a program and a text side by side?

Tags: positioning, line-numbering, code

My first question is how you write a program in LaTeX, with and without a line number for each line.

The second question is, because often my program is not too large, I want to save some space for text on its right hand side. So we could imagine two rectangle parts side by side: a program and some text. Could anyone tell me how to realize that?

Thank you very much!

**Edit1:** Now I have another need... I would like to have `l1, l2, l3...` to specify each line, instead of `1, 2, 3...`. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: By "text" are you referring commenting your program (or code)? Or do you want a more formal/lengthy discussion in paragraph style?

Comment: Its not clear to me exactly what you want. Are you trying to program LaTeX, or show C code for example? Please post a complete MWE (including `\documentclass`) of what you have tried already to clarify things.

Comment: @Werner, I do not want to comment my code, i just need a more formal/lengthy discussion in paragraph style...

Comment: @Peter Grill, I am not trying to program LaTeX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your program/code does not have to float around in your text, although it is also possible to construct something to that effect that floats in your document.

You can use the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) to generate a 2-column environment, placing your program/code on the left in a [`minipage` environment](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-267.html). This sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}% 2-column layout
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]% Taken from the algorithmicx package documentation
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{minipage}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis facilisis arcu, a malesuada elit vulputate quis. Duis et interdum eros. Maecenas ac sem at elit rutrum vehicula eu et elit. In convallis justo in arcu condimentum a adipiscing tortor auctor. Nam adipiscing ante sed ante vehicula tincidunt. Morbi volutpat purus tortor, a venenatis turpis. Vestibulum tristique augue ut dui cursus a aliquam velit volutpat.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Program code on left|decription on right]

Here you have to be careful that the description length does not exceed the program code. The program code above was produced using `algpseudocode` from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). The look of the algorithm can be changed in many ways, as suggested in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf). For instance, here is a different line numbering style (producing `l1`, `l2`,...,`l9`):

```
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize\texttt{l}#1:}% l1, l2, ...
```

[image: Algorithmicx showing a different line numbering style (<10 lines)]

As you can see, this works well for pseudocode that has less than 10 lines. To accommodate for more lines, you could use:

```
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize\texttt{l}\ifnum#1<10 \phantom{0}\fi #1:}% l 1, l 2, ... l 9, l10, l11, ...
```

[image: Algorithmicx showing a different line numbering style (<99 lines)]

Alternatively, placing the two respective components (program/code and description) in a minipage each would allow you to deviate from the length restriction, just like in @xport's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25019/how-to-place-a-program-and-a-text-side-by-side/25025#25025). The [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is used to import and format the code.

None of these approaches allow the program/code and description components to flow across pages, since the `minipage` environment does not break across pages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just another 1 question: what if i need to put `l1:` at the place of `1:`, `l2:` at the place of `2:`...?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume your program is written in Visual Basic, called it `VisualBasicCode.vb` as follows.

```vb
' VisualBasicCode.vb
Sub Signal(strSignalfolge As String, Optional lngTakt As Long = 100)
'Prozedur erzeugt eine Serie von Warntönen.
'Die optionale Variable lngTakt gibt den Takt in Millisekunden vor (Standard: 100 ms)
'Das Muster kann über die String-Variable strSignalfolge beeinflusst werden:
' Stern (*)     -> 1 Warnton
' Ziffern 1..9  -> 1..9 Takte Pause
' Leerzeichen   -> 1 Sekunde Pause
' Minus (-)     -> 1.5 Sekunden Pause
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim b As String
    For i = 1 To Len(strSignalfolge)
        b = Mid(strSignalfolge, i, 1)
        Select Case b
            Case "*": beep
            Case 1 To 9: DELAY CInt(b) * lngTakt
            Case " ": DELAY 1000
            Case "-": DELAY 1500
        End Select
        DELAY lngTakt
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function strParse(Data As String, Trenn As String, Nr As Integer)
'Funktion trennt die Zeichenkette <Data>
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MainData() As String, SplitData() As String
    MainData = Split(Data, Trenn)
    SplitData = Split(MainData(Nr - 1), Trenn)
    strParse = SplitData(0)
End Function


Public Sub ProtokollZeile(strData As String)
'Gibt eine Protokollzeile im Direktfenster aus: Datum, Uhrzeit und <strData>
    Debug.Print Now & " " & strData
End Sub

Sub NetSend(strmsg As String, Optional strEmpf As String = "imf3beck")
'Prozedur sendet die Kurznachricht <strMsg> über das Intranet an den Rechner <strEmpf>
    Dim a
    a = Shell("cmd.exe /c net send " & strEmpf & " " & strmsg, vbMinimizedFocus)
    MsgBox "(net send message)" & vbCr & strmsg
End Sub

Sub NetSendMessungBeendet(Optional strBem As String = "")
'Sendet über das Netzwerk eine Statusnachricht, dass die Messung beendet wurde und gibt diese
'Nachricht auch lokal als Warndialog aus
Dim strMsgText As String
strMsgText = (Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & " Messung beendet" & strBem)
NetSend (strMsgText)
End Sub

Public Function ZellBereichAdresse(strZellber As String) As String
Application.Volatile
ZellBereichAdresse = CStr(Range(strZellber).Address)
End Function
```

The TeX input file:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,lipsum}

\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=3,
    showstringspaces=false,
    aboveskip=-\fboxsep% it is needed to remove vertical white space
}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{
    extendedchars=\true,
    language={[Visual]Basic},
    frame=single,
    %===========================================================
    framesep=3pt,%expand outward.
    framerule=0.4pt,%expand outward.
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,%make the frame fits in the text area. 
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,%make the frame fits in the text area.
    %=========================================================== 
    rulecolor=\color{Red}
}

\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
    identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
    stringstyle=\color{Red},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}
}

\lstdefinestyle{B}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{White}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
    identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
    stringstyle=\color{Red},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\lstinputlisting[style=A]{VisualBasicCode.vb}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please try `style=B`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, which is not same as @Werner's. I have 1 questions: Should I put VisualBasicCode.vb in the same folder as the tex file?

Comment: `visualbasiccode.vb` should be placed in sub folder `codes` for better file management so you need to change `\lstinputlistings[style=A]{visualbasiccode.vb}` to `\lstinputlistings[style=A]{codes/visualbasiccode.vb}`.

Comment: @SoftTimur: Not necessarily. If you put it in the same folder as the .tex, then @xport's code will work as-is. If you want the file to be stored somewhere else, you should reference it using a relative path. Something like `\lstinputlisting[style=B]{code/vb/VisualBasicCode.vb}`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you may want to use `algorithm2e.sty`, which is a floating algorithm environment with algorithmic keywords. This can be found on CTAN at the following link:

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/

To number your algorithm use the `\LinesNumbered` command.  Because it is a floating algorithm environment, it may be possible to wrap text around it like you do for figures.  Not 100% sure on this as I have not tried it.  This, however, may or may not answer your second question.

Answer (score 0):

An other possibilty might be to create a floating container for your code with the [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and use the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to format your code See for example [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/how-to-get-autoref-working-with-different-counters-for-different-listing-environm/25050#25050). It should be possible to make this float behave like a wrapfigure, and thus be displayed next to your text.