# How can I place a displaymath environment and an align* environment side by side?

Tags: tables, positioning, align

I have a `displaymath` environment and an `align*` environment I would like to display next to each other. My idea was to wrap them in a `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  \[
    %math stuff here
  \]
  &
  \begin{align*}
    %laign stuff here
  \end{align*}
\end{tabular}
```

Both environments work fine on their own, but as soon as I add in `tabular`, the following error starts coming up (repeatedly):

```
Missing $ inserted.
```

I've also tried the `multicol` environment as suggested in [How to place a program and a text side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25019/how-to-place-a-program-and-a-text-side-by-side), but that just led to an error like the following:

```
Overfull \vbox blah blah blah
```

repeat like 20 times.

I am not able to get past this point. How can I get a `displaymath` environment and an `align*` environment to be side by side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
  \[
    A = B
  \]
  &
  \[
  \begin{aligned}
    a&= b \\
    c&= d
  \end{aligned}
  \]
\end{tabular}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \[
    A = B
  \]
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
    a&= b \\
    c&= d
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Second one worked, thank you very much! The first one was complaining about me using `\\[0.3em]` at the end of rows in `align*`.

Comment: @KPthunder You'll notice that I didn't use `align*` in the first one, but `aligned` within `displaymath`. Using `\\[0.3em]` works fine here.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Very good! I added an answer with an `align*` version, to show the OP that it could be used too, if the `&` for `align` is hidden from `tabular`.

Answer (score 8):

Also `align*` works in a `p` cell in a `tabular` environment. A trick to make it work, is grouping the `align*` environment by curly braces, so the `&`
 within align does not act like an `&` for `tabular`. Even `\\[length]` works.

A modification of Torbjørn's table in this way:

```
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
  \[
    A = B
  \]
  &
  {
    \begin{align*}
      a &= b \\[0.5ex]
      c &= d
    \end{align*}
  }
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is quite possible you need only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{aligned}
a &= 1 \\
b &= 1+2 \\
c &= 1+2+3 
\end{aligned}
&&
A = B
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Forget complex tabulars and boxes.