# Multiple listings styles

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions, naming

In using the `listings` package, how can I have a distinct `\lstlistingname` value for each type of listing.

Lets say my document has **C++, R** and **Pseudo** listings, and I would like the `\lstlistingname` value to be: `C++ Code`, `R Code` and `Pseudo Code` respectively, is it possible to define these values as part of the `\lstdefinestyle{...}` definition, rather than calling `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{...}` each time it needs changing?

Additionally, is it possible to have separate `list of listings` table in the front-matter of my document, for each type of listing style in preference to having all of the styles mixed into the same table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would define separate `lstlisting` environments for each of these entries using `\lstnewenvironment`. There you can reset the caption title and set the style the way you want to. Additionally, the code related to `\lstlistoflistings` from [`listings.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx) has been update to produce individual "List of ":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistcplusplusname}{List of C++}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofcplusplus{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcplusplusname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{cplusplus}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{C++ Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=C++,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistrcodename}{List of R}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofrcode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistrcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{rcode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{R Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=R,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lstlistofcplusplus
\lstlistofrcode
\lstlistofpseudocode

\begin{cplusplus}[caption={Hello world}]
// 'Hello World!' program 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{cplusplus}

\begin{rcode}[caption={Hello world}]
cat('Hello, world!\n')
\end{rcode}

\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
print "Hello world"
\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

Each listing patches the `\lst@MakeCaption` command to insert the appropriate file extension to write the contents-related macros. From the traditional `.lol` to `.loc` for C++ code, `.lor` for R code and `.lop` for Pseudocode.

It would be possible to update this to use separate counters for each listing as well. However, this would require a little more work.

<sub>Perhaps, as a reference for typesetting C++, see [Prettiest way to typeset “C++” (cplusplus)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4302/5764)</sub>

Comment: But how to use `\lstinputlisting` with the new environments?

Comment: works great! but how do you manage the numbering of each style independently? thanks