# Lstinputlisting and listings styles

Tags: listings, external-files

To further extend my recent question about new listings environments, found here: [Multiple listings styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/multiple-listings-styles).

How do I define a new `lstlistings` environment, via the command `\lstnewenvironment`, and, be able to use the command `\lstinputlisting` to draw the desired contents from file?

I am referring to newly created `lstlistingenvironments` via the command `\lstnewenvironment{MYENV}`. These are then accessed by

```
\begin{MYENV} 
BODY 
\end{MYENV}
```

Anything where `BODY` is, gets formatted, including the command \input{mycode.whatever}, instead of pulling the contents of the file `mycode.whatever` and formatting the contents.

Comment: No just code that I want to be formatted, ie a source file from an application.

Comment: Yeah but whats the way to read contents from file, and put it in the body of an environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file contains the appropriate listing environment (like `cplusplus` or `rcode`), then you can just use `\input{<filename>}`. If it doesn't (or just contains the raw code that should be formatted), you can create a new command that does all of the setup for you, just like it would for your `\lstnewenvironment` creations. The following can be used in conjunction with the solution in [Multiple listings styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113678/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents

\begin{filecontents*}{cplusplus.c}
// 'Hello World!' program 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{rcode.r}
cat('Hello, world!\n')
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{pseudocode.p}
print "Hello world"
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\lstlistcplusplusname}{List of C++}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofcplusplus{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcplusplusname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\newcommand{\lstinputcplusplus}[2][]{{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{C++ Code}%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loc}{##2}{##3}}%
  \lstinputlisting[language=C++,#1]{#2}%
}}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistrcodename}{List of R}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofrcode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistrcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\newcommand{\lstinputrcode}[2][]{{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{R Code}%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{lor}{##2}{##3}}%
  \lstinputlisting[language=R,#1]{#2}%
}}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\newcommand{\lstinputpseudocode}[2][]{{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{lop}{##2}{##3}}%
  \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1]{#2}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lstlistofcplusplus
\lstlistofrcode
\lstlistofpseudocode

\lstinputcplusplus[caption={Hello world}]{cplusplus.c}

\lstinputrcode[caption={Hello world}]{rcode.r}

\lstinputpseudocode[caption={Hello world}]{pseudocode.p}

\end{document}
```

The macros provided for inputting a listing of a specific type are `\lstinputcplusplus[<options>]{<filename>}`, `\lstinputrcode[<options>]{<filename>}` and `\lstinputpseudocode[<options>]{<filename>}`.

Comment: Excellent. Thankyou!. Works Perfectly.