# Add list of figures / tables only when content

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I add the list of figures, tables or listings to the frontmatter, ONLY when there is content in each respectively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is for the `article` class; adapt the redefinition of `\listoftables` in a similar way by copying the definition in the class you're using.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% We don't want to kill the table of contents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \global\@printlisttrue
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }

% redefine \listoftables to check for contents
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
  \check@list{lot}
  \if@printlist
    \section*{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
  \fi
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\def\@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@printlist
      \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \fi
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}
\newif\if@printlist

% We typeset the file in a box; if the box is empty, we don't input the file for real
\def\check@list#1{%
  \global\@printlistfalse
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{\makeatletter\@input{\jobname.#1}}%
  \ifdim\ht\z@>\z@\global\@printlisttrue\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftables

%%% uncomment the table for seeing the effect
%\begin{table}[htp]x\caption{y}\end{table}

abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is excellent, however, seems to be a clash when babel is being used. Do you get an error when `\usepackage[english]{babel}` or `\usepackage[australian]{babel}` is put in the preamble?

Comment: @ADP Yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: Great. Cheers..

Comment: I just realized it also killed the table of contents.

Comment: @ADP Yes; you have to redefine also `\tableofcontents` accordingly. I'll add it.

Comment: @egreg Why not offering something like `\ifchecklist{<counter>}{<code>}` so one could use `\ifchecklist{figure}{\listoffigures}`. (The file extension could be found in `\ext@<counter>`, e.g. `\ext@figure` is defined as `lof`.) As opposite to your solution this approach would not be dependent on the document class used anymore since no patching of `\listoffigures` etc. is needed here.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt The counter might reset at new sections. However your idea is good.

Comment: @egreg I do not see how counters, reset at new sections, do affect my idea about your solution, since (still) no counters are used at all? I'm confused...

Comment: @egreg `\newcommand\check@list[2]{\setbox\z@=\vbox{\makeatletter\@input{\jobname.#1}}\ifdim\ht\z@>\z@\relax#2\else\if@filesw\expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname\immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax\fi\fi}\newcommand\ifchecklist[1]{\check@list{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}}` - hopefully this makes it more clear what I had in mind.

Answer (score 16):

You could use the/my `totalcount` package for that purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}

\begin{document}
\iftotalfigures\listoffigures\fi
\iftotaltables\listoftables\fi
\iftotallstlistings\lstlistoflistings\fi

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

%\begin{table}
%\caption{A table}
%\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Useless code},label=useless,captionpos=t]
  for i:=maxint to 0 do
  begin
      { do nothing }
  end;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Please note that older versions of the `totalcount` package does not support the `lstlisting` counter, one need at least v1.0-92 for that.

Version v1.0-92 of the `totalcount` package can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tex/ (will upload it to CTAN today)

Comment: Excellent! Havn't tested yet but looks like a clean solution.

Comment: Will it work with newly defined lstlisting environments?

Comment: @ADP How do you actually define new listing environments? At least the one defined with `\lstnewenvironment` do use the same counter (lstlistings), so there should be no problem.

Comment: @ADP ...I just have found http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113679/2574 However, this solution (from Werner) does use own lists but not own counters for the newly defined environments, so in this case you need to use the solution offered by egreg since it checks for the content of the lists while the `totalcount` package is dependent on (separate) counters.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of a simple solution, with additional restrictions: `\caption` should be used, and `listof...` is at the end of a document.

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\ADPlistoftables{\ifnum\value{table}>0 \listoftables \else  \fi}
\def\ADPlistoffigures{\ifnum\value{figure}>0 \listoffigures \else  \fi}

\begin{document}

%\ADPlistoftables
%\ADPlistoffigures


\begin{figure}[!ht]
     \centering
 \caption{ }   
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!ht]
 \caption{ }   
\end{table}

\section{First}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
     \centering
 \caption{ }   
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!ht]
 \caption{ }   
\end{table}

\ADPlistoftables
\ADPlistoffigures


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the counters can get reset, say if the number format is `chapter` or `section` based.

Comment: @ADP You are right. It is a simplification, because I cannot imagine a real usage, when percent sign is easy to use.

Comment: Was waiting for a comment like that. But if you have a look at my recent post about different listings environments, and having a list of C code, list of R code and list of Pseudo code, now extend it to many other code variants, it is a safety net.

Comment: @ADP I hope that informing about it is not against the rules. I upvoted your question when it had only downvote, because i saw it's potential. However, a background of your question might be helpful in finding a good answer. And now I am going to study your other posts. :-)