# Unnecessary \addvspace in List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to conditionally-print a List of Figures and List of Tables only when the relevant elements exist. (I started by modifying the solution to this question: [Add list of figures/tables only when content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113769/add-list-of-figures-tables-only-when-content))

The following code works for the List of Figures (the first three/last three lines exist because I am modifying an existing thesis class and attempting to make minimal changes; my contribution is the middle two):

```
\newif\if@figures
\@figurestrue
\def\listoffigures{
  \newbox\tmpboxA\newbox\tmpboxB%
  \setbox\tmpboxA\vbox{\makeatletter\@input{\jobname.lof}}\setbox\tmpboxB\vbox{Figure 1}%
  \ifdim\ht\tmpboxA<\ht\tmpboxB\@figuresfalse\fi
  \if@figures\chapter*{List of Figures\markboth
  {LIST OF FIGURES}{LIST OF FIGURES}}\@starttoc{lof}\fi
}
```

However, doing the same for the List of Tables does not work:

```
\newif\if@tables
\@tablestrue
\def\listoftables{
  \newbox\tmpboxA\newbox\tmpboxB%
  \setbox\tmpboxA\vbox{\makeatletter\@input{\jobname.lot}}\setbox\tmpboxB\vbox{Table 1}%
  \ifdim\ht\tmpboxA<\ht\tmpboxB\@tablesfalse\fi
  \if@tables\chapter*{List of Tables\markboth
  {LIST OF TABLES}{LIST OF TABLES}}\@starttoc{lot}\fi
}
```

I can see that this is because `\jobname.lof` is empty, while `\jobname.lot` contains six 
`\addvspace{10pt}` (one for each chapter). Is there a way around this/a better way to handle this?

**Edit:** after cleaning out the directory, the problem seems to be that the `\@starttoc` command is responsible for generating the files `\jobname.lof` and `\jobname.lot`. So testing the size of the list can't work until `\@starttoc` is called?

Comment: There is certainly a simpler way how to check that there's no table. Anyways: if `.lof` and `.lot` differ in the number of lines `\addvspace{...}` they contain, the class is corrupted since the files should be exactly the same in this manner; it's the top sectioning command (`\chapter` or `\section`) that inserts the space there (in both of them by default). Could you add a full MWE?

Comment: @yo' I'm having trouble figuring out a MWE because the .cls file involved is large, and I'm making only minor edits to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use the second answer in the linked question and use the totalcount package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\RequirePackage[figure,table]{totalcount}

\begin{document}
\iftotaltables
   \listoftables
\fi

\iftotalfigures
   \listoffigures
\fi

\begin{figure}
blal
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you could try, it is a complete minimal example. (The answer is: it needs three compilations, after the first the boolean for figure is true).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. Although, would it be possible to do this in "raw" TeX/LaTeX, without the package import? It seems like it shouldn't be that hard... famous last words when LaTeX is concerned.

Comment: Sure copy the code of the package in your class. But imho it is against the spirit of latex not to use (good and useful) packages.

Comment: Ha! I'm not against using packages, I was just hoping to make a decent, sharable edit that wouldn't rely on outside sources if a handful of lines could avoid it. (as is, I'm only writing one thesis, so omitting the List of Figures/Tables is as simple as not including it)