# change caption of multiple listing styles

Tags: macros, listings, environments

I want to have different listing environments, each with an own caption.

My try was this (vorlage.tex):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codecolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{chatcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.8}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings


\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- Chat-Auszug
\newcommand{\lstlistchatname}{Chat-Auszug}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofchat{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistchatname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{chat}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Chat}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{chatcolor}
}}{}

% --------------------------------------- Code
\newcommand{\lstlistcodename}{Code}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpycode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pycode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{codecolor},
}}{}

% linksbündige Fußboten
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\typearea{14} % typearea berechnet einen sinnvollen Satzspiegel (das heißt die Seitenränder) siehe auch http://www.ctan.org/pkg/typearea. Diese Berechnung befindet sich am Schluss, damit die Einstellungen oben berücksichtigt werden

\usepackage{scrhack} % Vermeidung einer Warnung
```

Then using like this:

```
\input{vorlage.tex}
\begin{document}

\lstlistofchat
\lstlistofpycode

\begin{pycode}[caption={Import nltk}]
import nltk
\end{pycode}

\begin{chat}[caption={Talking...}]
Sadik: Hello
\end{chat}

\end{document}
```

This is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113679/102325)

The different background colors are applied, so the style lstset works. But the caption is not displayed at all.

[image]

For the first example the caption should be something like **Chat-Auszug 1.1** *Import NLTK* and for the second example something like **Code 1.1** *Talking...*. Both are not displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to  TeX.SX! Fragments of code are not really useful. Please provide a compilable document. And you need the `float` option, as far as I know

Comment: I updated the answer and added almost the whole document, although this is not going to help in my opinion. Why does it need to be compilable? I can't post thousands of lines of code here.
What is the float option?

Comment: The example should be compilable so that we can test the issue. It should be small so that we don't have to much work when trying to find out what's going on. So make a real sensible minimal example. Remove the parts that are not necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: ok, now it's compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code holds specified parameters, but they haven't been told the environments to be used. See comments in code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codecolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{chatcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.8}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings


\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- Chat-Auszug
\newcommand{\lstlistchatname}{Chat-Auszug}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofchat{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistchatname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{chat}[1][]{% <<--- is told to expect a parameter
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Chat}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{chatcolor}, #1 %<--- forgot to use #1. 
}}{}

% --------------------------------------- Code
\newcommand{\lstlistcodename}{Code}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpycode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pycode}[1][]{%   <<--- is told to expect a parameter
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{codecolor}, #1 %<---forgot to use #1, same as above
}}{}

% linksbündige Fußboten
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\typearea{14} % typearea berechnet einen sinnvollen Satzspiegel (das heißt die Seitenränder) siehe auch http://www.ctan.org/pkg/typearea. Diese Berechnung befindet sich am Schluss, damit die Einstellungen oben berücksichtigt werden

\usepackage{scrhack} % Vermeidung einer Warnung

\begin{document}

    \lstlistofchat
    \lstlistofpycode

    \begin{pycode}[caption={Import nltk}]
        import nltk
    \end{pycode}

    \begin{chat}[caption={Talking...}]
        Sadik: Hello
    \end{chat}

\end{document}
```