# Multiple listing styles with caption package

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, listings, naming

This question is mainly related to [Multiple listings styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/multiple-listings-styles). If I have `\usepackage{caption}` definition in the head of file, list of custom listings disappear. How to make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistcplusplusname}{List of C++}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofcplusplus{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcplusplusname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{cplusplus}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{C++ Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=C++,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistrcodename}{List of R}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofrcode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistrcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{rcode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{R Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=R,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lstlistofcplusplus
\lstlistofrcode
\lstlistofpseudocode

\begin{cplusplus}[caption={Hello world}]
// 'Hello World!' program 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{cplusplus}

\begin{rcode}[caption={Hello world}]
cat('Hello, world!\n')
\end{rcode}

\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
print "Hello world"
\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package needs to patch `\lst@MakeCaption` to adapt the `listings` package to the features of the `caption` package. It stores (and uses) the original definition of `\lst@MakeCaption` into a macro called `\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption`, so to make your solution work, this macro needs to be patched:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistcplusplusname}{List of C++}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofcplusplus{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcplusplusname
    \let\lst@temp@starttoc \def@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{cplusplus}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{C++ Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=C++,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistrcodename}{List of R}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofrcode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistrcodename
    \let\lst@temp@starttoc \def@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{rcode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{R Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=R,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
    \let\lst@temp@starttoc \def@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}`

\lstlistofcplusplus
\lstlistofrcode
\lstlistofpseudocode

\begin{cplusplus}[caption={Hello world}]
// 'Hello World!' program

## include

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{cplusplus}

\begin{rcode}[caption={Hello world}]
cat('Hello, world!\n')
\end{rcode}

\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
print "Hello world"
\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}

It's a pity that the `listings` feature does not define and use `\def\ext@lstlisting{lol}`, like all other environments which do offer a "List of" feature. In this case redefining `\ext@lstlisting` would be sufficient, with and without `caption` package (or any other package patching `\lst@MakeCaption`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Axel. Can you elaborate why this does not work for beamer document class? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Sezen What problems do you have when using beamer? When I replace `article` with `beamer` the document will still compile fine. The lists are missing, the reason for this is that `beamer` simply does not support lists.

Comment: The issue was simply list of listings does not appear in beamer. Your answer is what I was after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `caption` package, I found the `capt-of` package in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of). When I used this package everything worked smoothly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistcplusplusname}{List of C++}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofcplusplus{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistcplusplusname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{cplusplus}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{C++ Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=C++,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistrcodename}{List of R}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofrcode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistrcodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{rcode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{R Code}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=R,#1}}
  {}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lstlistofcplusplus
\lstlistofrcode
\lstlistofpseudocode

\begin{cplusplus}[caption={Hello world}]
// 'Hello World!' program 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{cplusplus}

\begin{rcode}[caption={Hello world}]
cat('Hello, world!\n')
\end{rcode}

\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
print "Hello world"
\end{pseudocode}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Example image a.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `caption` is widely used package and has a lot of methods like `captionsetup` to change captions. I really would like to have a solution with caption package.

Comment: It's not clear to me why do you think this is a clash between `regexpatch` and `caption`.

Comment: As I said, it was just the assumption.