# Adding a Caption to \lstnewenvironment using \mdframed

Tags: listings, captions, mdframed, sourcecode

I found on the Internet the piece of LaTeX code I really liked :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed,xcolor}

\definecolor{codeBackground}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.8}
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}{
  \lstset{
    moredelim=**[is][\bfseries]{|}{|},% bold everything in between ||
    moredelim=**[is][\itshape]{*}{*}  % italic everything in between **
  }%
\mdframed[backgroundcolor=codeBackground,shadow=true,shadowsize=2pt,shadowcolor=black!30]%
}{%
  \endmdframed\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


\begin{mylisting}
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add numbered caption to this source code, but neither

```
\begin{mylisting}{caption=code caption}
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}
```

nor:

```
\begin{mylisting} \caption{code caption}
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}
```

does work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can require a new parameter to your environment which contains the caption, and use `\captionof` from the `caption` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed,xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{codeBackground}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.8}
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1]{
  \lstset{
    moredelim=**[is][\bfseries]{|}{|},% bold everything in between ||
    moredelim=**[is][\itshape]{*}{*}  % italic everything in between **
  }%
\mdframed[backgroundcolor=codeBackground,shadow=true,shadowsize=2pt,shadowcolor=black!30]%
}{%
  \endmdframed
  \captionof{lstlisting}{#1}
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


\begin{mylisting}{My Caption}
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `caption` to `\lstset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed,xcolor}

\definecolor{codeBackground}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.8}
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
  \lstset{
    moredelim=**[is][\bfseries]{|}{|},% bold everything in between ||
    moredelim=**[is][\itshape]{*}{*},  % italic everything in between **
    caption={[#1]{#1}}        %%<---------------------- here
  }%
\mdframed[backgroundcolor=codeBackground,shadow=true,shadowsize=2pt,shadowcolor=black!30]%
}{%
  \endmdframed
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


\begin{mylisting}[My Caption]
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}

Some text here
\begin{mylisting}
public |class| Test {
  public *static |void|* main(String[] argumente) {
    System.out.println("Hallo Welt!");
  }
}
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it more general by

```
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
  \lstset{
    moredelim=**[is][\bfseries]{|}{|},% bold everything in between ||
    moredelim=**[is][\itshape]{*}{*},  % italic everything in between **
    #1
  }%
```

so that more options to `lstset` can be added on the fly like

```
\begin{mylisting}[caption={My Caption}]
```