# Change caption name of multiple listings

Tags: captions, lstdefinestyle

Can you please help me modify the listing names as shown in the image attached.  I currently have 4 different `\lstdefinestyle` and would like to then have 4 different listing names.  I was trying to follow the [solution given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments) to modify the listings names but I could not get the code to work properly.

Any help to get the listing names changed as shown in the image, is sincerely appreciated!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

%\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblueiii},
    tabsize=6
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystylecode}{
    language=C,
    numbers=none,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    keywords={real},
    backgroundcolor=\color{codegray!10}
}

\begin{filecontents}{result_1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
Root mean squared error                  3.7905
Relative absolute error                 76.7091 %
Root relative squared error             81.3406 %
Total Number of Instances              188

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result_2.txt}
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
style=mystylecode,
caption={Code Snippet.},
label = R1]{result_2.txt}

\lstinputlisting[
style=mystyleresults,
caption={Results from run 1.},
label = bilateral1GPA]{result_1.txt}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre
\end{codeblock}

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor,caption=Sample code from Matlab]{sample.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have multiple listings environments, but they all use the same counter `lstlisting`, so what do you expect?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, how do you go about changing the counter then?  Thanks.

Comment: No easy solution for this, in my point of view

Comment: The easiest way is to use `\newtcbinputlistings` instead of the `\lstinputlistings` and use `tcolorbox` features

Comment: But that can change the caption labels?

Comment: Yes, but I think you're using the wrong setup anyway. Why mixing `\lstinputlisting` and `tcolorbox` listings? Chose one style. The listings style is awkward, anyway. You should drop the `\lstinputlistings`, in my point of view. You should use a specific code block for `python`, for matlab etc, not one single codeblock environment

Comment: I have a solution for the codeblock environment concerning the counter value..., but no elegant one for the `\lstinputlisting` stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you for your time...I am not sure that I am following you when you mention, "You should use a specific code block for `python`, for `matlab` etc.".  Am I not doing that when I use the `\lstdefinestyle`?  Thanks.

Comment: No, you would have to give it to the `tcolorbox` listing to activate it (maybe just using an optional parameter for the environment and giving that to `listing options`). Anyway, to change the names you have to renew `\lstlistingname`. That's what prints this text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just introduced some new commands for inputting your data according to type. They switch between the styles and of course are fully based on `tcolorbox`. Hence you have to style them according to your needs, but the manual [here](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) is very good.

[image: listings]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

%\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=pythoncode]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Python Code~\thepythoncode~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1},after upper={\centering\strut Python Code~\thepythoncode:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data]{\inputdata}[3][]{listing options={style=mystylecode},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
     listing file={#3}}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result]{\inputresult}[3][]{listing options={style=mystyleresults},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
     listing file={#3}}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{listing options={style=Matlab-editor},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1},after upper={\centering\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab:~#2},%
     listing file={#3}}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblueiii},
    tabsize=6
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystylecode}{
    language=C,
    numbers=none,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    keywords={real},
    backgroundcolor=\color{codegray!10}
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
Root mean squared error                  3.7905
Relative absolute error                 76.7091 %
Root relative squared error             81.3406 %
Total Number of Instances              188

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\inputdata{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}
\inputresult{Result from run 1}{result1.txt}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre
\end{codeblock}

\inputmatlab{Sample matlab code}{sample.m}

\end{document}
```