# Independent caption and numbers on different lstlisting language script

Tags: captions, listings, languages, code

I'm trying to write a document where I use AMPL, Python and I would also like to be able to show some of the outputs.

Problem is that the first python code is Script 1, the first AMPL is script 2, the second python is script 3, the output of the first python code is script 4, and so.

I want the different languages to be independent, a different counter and caption for the AMPL scripts, for the Python scripts and for the outputs.

Is this possible?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this answer can be readily adapted to produce different listings for different languages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4068/106804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4068/106804) to [Listings: different counters for different listing environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments/3998#3998) I think this might be what you're after:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{pythoncode}
\lstnewenvironment{pythoncode}[2]{
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Python Code}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{pythoncode}}
\lstset
{
language={},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
frame = tb,
caption={[#1]{#1}},
label={#2},        
}
} {\addtocounter{pythoncode}{1}}

\newcounter{amplcode}
\lstnewenvironment{amplcode}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{AMPL Code}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{amplcode}}
    \lstset
    {
    language={},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame = tb,
    caption={[#1]{#1}},
    label={#2},        
    }
} {\addtocounter{amplcode}{1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Examples}
\begin{pythoncode}{Hello world in Python 2}{alg-label}
print "Hello world"
\end{pythoncode}

\begin{pythoncode}{Hello world in Python 3}{another-alg-label}
print("Hello world")
\end{pythoncode}

\begin{amplcode}{\texttt{blend.mod}}{prg-label}
set INPUT;    # inputs
set OUTPUT;   # outputs
...
\end{amplcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm after, Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I'm having another trouble now... do you know if there is a way to merge this solution with lstinputlisting?
My scripts are on files that I'm still working on and will change several times to.
I tried giving the file in an argument and doing inputpath{#3}, but it didn't work

Comment: @JPabloFuenzalida At a glance I'm not to sure. Perhaps you can ask it in its own question.